# how to format result of json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

first i have this result with json_ncode :

```
[{"name":"Pendapatan","y":"1464333560100.00"},{"name":"realpen","y":"500831727342.91"},{"name":"Belanja","y":"1074625188660.00"},{"name":"realbel","y":"239521231607.23"},{"name":"Pembiayaan","y":"52029536970.00"},{"name":"realpem","y":"1809194488.25"}]
```

when i use str_replace('"','', $result); the data become like this :

```
[{name:Pendapatan,y:1464333560100.00},{name:realpen,y:500831727342.91},{name:Belanja,y:1074625188660.00},{name:realbel,y:239521231607.23},{name:Pembiayaan,y:52029536970.00},{name:realpem,y:1809194488.25}]
```

What format should I use to remove the "[]", and leaving only the {a: val, b: val .... etc}

Comment: What do you really want to achive? Why dont't you `json_decode($array, true);`? And then you can build what you want.

Comment: If you remove the `[]`, it will become invalid JSON. Removing the quotes makes it invalid as well. Why are you trying to make it invalid?

Comment: Do you want to only remove quotes around the numbers? What's the data from which you generated the JSON?

Comment: i'll call that format result in javascript ...ex 
<script>
result : [<? myphpvar ?>]
</script>

this ok ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
substr($yourJson, 1, -1);
```

Although it is debatable if you *should* do that this way, as some users in comments already said.